# Timer and onChange

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, settimeout

I need to run the `goTo()` function cautiously because it would download a large image each time, so to skip the *unintended* changes, I'm checking if the **value has changed** `and` a certain **time has elapsed** (2000ms).

```
scrubber.onValueChanged = function (value) {
    var timer;
    if (gallery.getCurrentIndex() !== value) {
        console.log('value changed');
        clearTimeout(timer); console.log('timer reset');
    }
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('updating...');
      gallery.goTo(value);
    }, 2000);
};
```

.. this works but it **doesn't** skip the changes it should, it still runs the `goTo()` function for ALL the values I have moved from, to and in-between.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`timer` is a local variable. So every time the function is called `timer` is being reset and `clearTimeout(timer)` doesn't work as expected. To fix that move `timer` variable outside the function scope or make it global.

```
var timer;
....
scrubber.onValueChanged = function (value) {
    if (gallery.getCurrentIndex() !== value) {
        console.log('value changed');
        clearTimeout(timer); console.log('timer reset');
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
          console.log('updating...');
          gallery.goTo(value);
        }, 2000);
    }

};
```

Comment: Moved the timer variable outside but its still the same. http://postimg.org/image/hge1o3dz3/, and it keeps on updating until I refresh the page.

Comment: Is `onValueChanged` called even if value was not actually changed? Why?

Comment: Maybe not, but it appears so, because say I'm on `1` and I use the scrubber, move around a bit and back to `1`, it returns all the values I have been through from `1` and back to `1`.